# RecyclerView call LoadMore pagination continuously

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, pagination

I'm trying to implement pagination using code below, and it work well with fragments, but when i implemented it in Nested Fragment it load all data (load first page and all next pages continuously). The problem is that my total items is 12 and visible in time is 3 but layoutManager.getChildCount() give me 12 same as total item (layoutManager.getItemCount()) so it start loading next pages continuously.

Here is oNScroll code :

```
  public PaginationScrollListener(LinearLayoutManager layoutManager) {
    this.layoutManager = layoutManager;
}

@Override
public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

    int visibleItemCount = layoutManager.getChildCount();
    int totalItemCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();
    int firstVisibleItemPosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

    if (!isLoading() && !isLastPage()) {
        if ((visibleItemCount + firstVisibleItemPosition) >= totalItemCount
                && firstVisibleItemPosition >= 0
                && totalItemCount >= getTotalPageCount()) {
            loadMoreItems();
        }
    }

}
```

When scroll and request next pages :

```
        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new PaginationScrollListener(layoutManager) {
        @Override
        protected void loadMoreItems() {
            isLoading = true;
            currentPage += 1;

            // mocking network delay for API call
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    loadNextPage();
                }
            }, 1000);
        }

        @Override
        public int getTotalPageCount() {
            return TOTAL_PAGES;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isLastPage() {
            return isLastPage;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isLoading() {
            return isLoading;
        }
    });
```

Comment: I used it already but i have got same problem, it loadInitial() and loadAfter() called continuously also.., thats when i implemented it in Nested Fragment but in Fragment it work well

Comment: i have got same issue, it keep calling loadAfter continuously...

Answer (score 0):

change your scroll listener like below:

```
@Override
public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
if(dy>0){  //if is scrolling vertically
   int visibleItemCount = layoutManager.getChildCount();
   int totalItemCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();
   int firstVisibleItemPosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
   if (!isLoading() && !isLastPage()) {
      if (firstVisibleItemPosition + visibleItemCount >= totalItemCount) {
      //make your request here
   }
}
}});
```

Comment: i changed to firstVisibleItemPosition (i used to name like that)

Comment: are you increasing the page number before making your request in:
if (firstVisibleItemPosition + visibleItemCount >= totalItemCount) {
      //make your request here
   }

Comment: its same it load all data

Comment: may i see your request if is possible